# SecItemCopyMatching OSStatus

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I'm getting -34018 back when using SecItemCopyMatching. I did not find any documentation what this error code means. Maybe somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements"

Comment: Interesting thanks. I've noticed that this happens when my App gets killed while in background (e.g. to much memory consumption). When i start the app again i get this error. Have you any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Many (all?) Security framework error codes are defined in `SecBase.h`, a header file that is part of the Security framework. You can also find this file in [Apple's open-source Security framework](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-58286.41.2/base/SecBase.h.auto.html).

Error code -34018 is defined thus:

```
errSecMissingEntitlement                 = -34018,    /* A required entitlement isn't present. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSString *NSStringFromOSStatus(OSStatus errCode)
    {
        if (errCode == noErr)
            return @"noErr";
        char message[5] = {0};
        *(UInt32*) message = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(errCode);
        return [NSString stringWithCString:message encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
```

Comment: This is how you should do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196869/how-do-you-convert-an-iphone-osstatus-code-to-something-useful/23708500#23708500

Comment: It's still not as good as my answer, which gives a full textural message, but cannot be included in the product due to using deprecated methods.

Comment: What are the deprecated methods I used that code and build the project in ios7 sdk it doesn't show any deprecated method? Can you specify that methods?

Comment: I'm talking about my answer in the linked question - it uses deprecated Carbon methods, and can only run under OSX.  However it does produce proper messages, where as the accepted answer in that link, and your answer, just produce meaningless 4-character strings in some cases and nothing useful at all in other cases.