# AudioOutputUnitStart failed with OSStatus = -66637 (How to print OSStatus from c++)

Tags: c++, ios

I faced with issue when the AudioOutputUnitStart failed on start recording.

!!! I have already found the root cause without this returned code: it happens because of AVAudioSessionCategory was set incorrectly. !!!

But I spend a lot of time to find what means OSStatus = -66637, I also tried to convert this message to hex, byte(0xFFFEFBB3 = 11111111 11111110 11111011 10110011)

I know about this site: https://www.osstatus.com but there is no info about -66637(in all types of conversion)
Also I have tried macerror, but there are no codes for iOS.

Could someone help to find what means -66637?

And logs in our project was done in printf format, so I print OSStatus like this: "%d",status, maybe it is not correct, could someone suggest the best way to print OSStatus from c++ code?

This question was very useful to me: [How do you convert an IPhone OSStatus code to something useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2196869/6034634)
but even with all answers which was there, I couldn't find the one which could help me.

Comment: I'd start by finding the header file where the function is defined and have a look around for *localized* (to the framework) status codes.  There is no one-stop-shop for status codes...

Comment: Suggestions to improve your question to assist the SO community help you find a solution... you mention you're programming iOS, so include the relevant lines of the error message in context, instead of just `OSStatus = -66637`; include the relevant lines of code you've tried; don't abbreviate words (mb).

Comment: @andrewbuilder, thank you for your advice, but  as I mentioned earlier I have already found the solution, I just need to find what means OSStatus = -66637 and the best way to print OSStatus from c++ code.

Answer (score 2):

I got -66637, when I tried to start recording by set `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`. Changing to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` the code return 0.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is facing this issue more recently: I had to make sure that my `AVAudioSession`, once properly setup, was also activated by calling [`setActive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616627-setactive).